# how to set up a mail server and send emails using python SMTP

Tags: python-3.x, server, dns, smtp, vps

I would like to send an email with Python smtplib from a custom email address that is linked to a gmail account. The address ends with '.org'. I set up the App Password on the gmail account that the address is linked to. This is my code:

```
def send_email_from_gmail(**kwargs):
    '''
    kwparams:
    receivers: list
    event_datetime: str
    event_name: str
    parent_name: str
    event_date: str
    event_time: str
    student_name: str
    location: str,
    location_link: str
    '''
    email_data = json.load(open('email_info.json'))

    receivers = kwargs['receivers']
    sender = email_data['email_address']

    msg = EmailMessage()
    msg['Subject'] = email_data['subject'].format(kwargs['event_datetime'], kwargs['event_name'])
    msg['From'] = sender
    msg['To'] = receivers

    msg.set_content(email_data['email'].format(kwargs['parent_name'], kwargs['event_date'], kwargs['event_time'], kwargs['student_name'], kwargs['location'], kwargs['location_link']))

    app_pass = email_data['email_pass']

    with smtplib.SMTP_SSL(host='smtp.gmail.com', port=465) as smtp:
        try:
            smtp.login(sender, app_pass)
            smtp.send_message(msg)
            return {'success': True}
        except:
            return {'success': False}
```

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ayushpal/MatrixLearning/websitebackend/email_testing.py", line 55, in <module>
    print(send_email_from_gmail(**sample_args))
  File "/Users/ayushpal/MatrixLearning/websitebackend/email_testing.py", line 33, in send_email_from_gmail
    with smtplib.SMTP_SSL(host='smtp.matrixlearning.org', port=587) as smtp:
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/smtplib.py", line 1050, in __init__
    SMTP.__init__(self, host, port, local_hostname, timeout,
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/smtplib.py", line 255, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/smtplib.py", line 341, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/smtplib.py", line 1056, in _get_socket
    new_socket = super()._get_socket(host, port, timeout)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/smtplib.py", line 312, in _get_socket
    return socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout,
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/socket.py", line 824, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/socket.py", line 955, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

If I set the host to 'smtp.{my-domain}.***com***' instead of '.org', the program runs for about 5 minutes without doing anything before timing out and losing connection.

How can I solve this?

Comment: 7 lines of code doesn't describe what you are intended to do, if i take this 7 lines of code and run it then it doesn't make any sense if it needs to be debug you need to provide fully functioning code so we can do research on it.

Comment: @MdAdil I added the full function I am using. I am not going to share the emails or passwords.

Comment: on line no 33 in file email_testing.py it says smtp.matrixlearning.org, instead try smtp.gmail.com

Comment: This is what I get: ssl.SSLError: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1123)

Comment: matrixlearning.org is your domain???

Comment: yes, it is a custom domain that I linked to my gmail account.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247164/discussion-between-mdadil-and-ayush).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to attach the mailbox of my custom domain server to gmail before using gmail as the server to send emails. Thank you to everyone who answered!

Answer (score 0):

According to DNS queries from my comp `smtp.matrixlearning.org` has no DMS records so it can not be mapped to IP address.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
…
  File "/Users/ayushpal/MatrixLearning/websitebackend/email_testing.py", line 33, in send_email_from_gmail
    with smtplib.SMTP_SSL(host='smtp.matrixlearning.org', port=587) as smtp:
…
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

Answer (score 0):

I think gmail isn't allowing to use third-party apps anymore. I've just seen this on the security settings of gmail:

"To help keep your account secure, **from May 30, 2022**, ​​Google no longer supports the use of third-party apps or devices which ask you to sign in to your Google Account using only your username and password."